# HTML - Autocomplet off don't work for address or credit card

Tags: html, autocomplete

When I set the autocomplete attribute to off on an input, it doesn't work to stop address or credit card autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there really is no way to truly disable autocomplete in most browsers. Firefox for example will gleefully ignore your request, and instead uses `autocomplete=off` to simply disable the autofilling of input values *on page load*, but if the user clicks into the field, the autocomplete will come up.

`autocomplete=off` is the "correct" way to achieve this, but it almost certainly ignored.

Answer (score -1):

The autocomplete behavior of web browsers can sometimes be inconsistent, and the **autocomplete="off"** attribute does not guarantee that the browser will disable autocomplete for specific fields like addresses or credit cards. Browsers often prioritize user convenience and may override the autocomplete attribute in certain cases.

To minimize autocomplete suggestions for sensitive information like addresses and credit cards, you can try a few alternative approaches:

Randomize field names: Instead of using standard field names like "address" or "credit card number," you can use unique or random names for those fields. This approach may confuse the browser's autocomplete mechanism and prevent it from offering suggestions.

Use JavaScript: You can utilize JavaScript to clear or manipulate the field values programmatically. For example, you can clear the value of an address field after it has been entered, preventing the browser from remembering and suggesting it in the future.

Implement server-side handling: If the autocomplete behavior is crucial for security reasons, you can handle the sensitive data on the server-side rather than relying on client-side autocomplete. By submitting the form data to the server and processing it there, you can have more control over the handling of sensitive information.

Remember that while these approaches can help mitigate autocomplete behavior, they might not be foolproof, as browsers can still interpret and apply their own autocomplete algorithms. Therefore, it's important to consider the security implications of handling sensitive data in your web application and adopt additional security measures as necessary.